# Mysterious segmentation fault on function return with no pointers or allocation involved

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, return

I am currently writing some C++ code that does a lot of text parsing. One feature pushes chars into a string after checking if the char is a visible char (as opposed to whitespace). However, when I run the code below:

```
void myWords::pushChar(char c){ 
    myChar cc;
    std::cout<< "before if" <<std::endl;
    if(!(cc.isWS(c))){
        std::cout<< "after if" <<std::endl;
        myList.back();
    }
    else if((myList.back()).size()>0){
        myList.push_back("");
    }
}
```

Which calls the following code block:

```
bool myChar::isWS(char c){ // returns true if char is whitespace
    std::cout<< "comparing" <<std::endl;
    if((c >= '!') && (c <= '~')){
       std::cout<< "compared" <<std::endl;
       return false;
    }
    else {
        std::cout<< "compared" <<std::endl;
        return true;
    }
}
```

When these functions run, I (sometimes) get a segmentation fault immediately after the "compared" is printed by myChar::isWS(). There are no pointers/dereferences in my code (although I assume C++ implements STL containers with some pointing behind the scenes), and there is no memory accessing at that point aside from the return call. I ran Valgrind with the code, which has told me that there is an invalid memory access taking place.

What types of things could cause this kind of issue with no pointers/dereferences? Is there some way I could have corrupted the stack with that code?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show the *exact* Valgrind message?

Comment: On line 6 of pushChar you are just referencing the back of the list myList.back () which will seg fault on an empty list. Did you mean to use push_back here? That line doesn't do anything otherwise.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, Valgrind returns the following: 

Invalid read of size 8
  at 0x4EF0860: std::string::size() const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
  by 0x40291B: myWords::pushChar(char) (marcstr.cpp:70)

Comment: @DavidWoo, yes, I originally had myList.back().push_back(c) there, but I started removing things from that line (one at a time) to see if any of it was causing the error. The segfault comes before "after if" can print.

Comment: Your error looks like you are calling size on non-existent object returned when you have an empty list. I.e in the second if statement. You need to check for an empty list before you can use  back () safely.

Comment: @DavidWoo THANK YOU!!! That took care of the issue.

Comment: @mwarrior Re: Valgrind. That's not *all* that Valgrind tells you. I asked for *exact* Valgrind message, and you failed to supply one. In the future, you'll get better answer faster if you edit your question and supply the exact info requested, not a part of it. P.S. You should build your code with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` flag. It would have showed you the problem right away.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, my apologies, this is one of my first posts. I'll make sure apply that to my future posts/replies. Also, thank you for the flag suggestion, sounds very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your error looks like you are calling size on non-existent object returned when you have an empty list. I.e in the second if statement. You need to check for an empty list before you can use  back () safely.

I am guessing you want to something like this

```
void myWords::pushChar(char c)
{ 
    if( !isWhitespace (c) )
    {
        myList.push_back(c);
    }
    else 
    {
       if( !myList.empty() && (myList.back().size()>0) ) // is last element a non-empty string ?
       {
         myList.push_back("");  // then push an empty string on to list
       }
    }
 }
```

It would be helpful to know how myList is declared and what the intended logic is in pushChar.

Comment: myList is a vector of strings, and I wanted to do myList.back().push_back(c). Your comment (above) about using back() on an empty vector was the issue.